# A particular meaning of the phrasal verb 'work out' in AmE

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Could someone please tell me if in AmE the phrasal verb "work out" in the sense of "finding an answer to a question" is in common use and sounds natural and idiomatic to everyone or not; (I think it is used only in BE!) Please have a look on the following example:

> - I still can’t **work out** how they knew about our relationship. --- I don't know too.

Comment: This really is a dictionary look-up question. Most dictionaries give you the option of looking up a word in AmE or BrE. Or, they will tell you in a definition if the word is particularly AmE or BrE.

Answer (score 2):

It is used in American English in the same way.

http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student?book=Student&va=work%20out

Comment: I agree that it's grammatical and understandable. Still, I think _figure out_ might be more common in this context.